# JavaScript. Удалить элемент из JSON по значению ключа

Tags: javascript, json

Есть массив - `arrJSON` и есть значение ключа `var useID = "Mistake_1"`, 
нужно найти в массиве элемент по значению ключа и удалить этот элемент.
В результате, массив `arrJSON` будет иметь следующий вид:

```
[
 title: "text1", id: "Mistake_0", names: "Mistake",
 title: "text3", id: "Task_1", names: "Task"
]
```

входные данные:

```
var useID = "Mistake_1";

var arrJSON = [
{title: "text1", id: "Mistake_0", names: "Mistake"}, 
{title: "text2", id: "Mistake_1", names: "Mistake"}, 
{title: "text3", id: "Task_1", names: "Task"}
];
```

Comment: Есть массив - (arrJSON) и есть значение ключа (var useID = "Mistake_1"), нужно найти в массиве элемент по значению ключа и удалить этот элемент. В результате, массив (arrJSON) будет иметь следующий вид: title: "text1", id: "Mistake_0", names: "Mistake" title: "text3", id: "Task_1", names: "Task"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например используя метод [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) ищем индекс нужного элемента и удаляем используя оператор [delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```js
var useID = "Mistake_1";

var arrJSON = [
  {title: "text1", id: "Mistake_0", names: "Mistake"},
  {title: "text2", id: "Mistake_1", names: "MistakeN"},
  {title: "text3", id: "Task_1", names: "Task"}
]
document.getElementById('div_1').innerHTML = useID;
var indexDel = arrJSON.findIndex(function(item){ return item.id === useID } );
var newarr = arrJSON.filter(function(item){ return item.id !== useID } );
delete(arrJSON[indexDel]);
document.getElementById("div_2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arrJSON);
document.getElementById("div_2").innerHTML += ' lenght='+arrJSON.length;

document.getElementById("div_3").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newarr);
document.getElementById("div_3").innerHTML += ' lenght='+newarr.length;
```

```css
body{ background-color: #20262e; color: #cfd0d2; }
```

```html
<div id="div_1">1</div>
<div id="div_2">2</div><hr/>
<div id="div_3">3</div>
```

Comment: Далее столкнулся с тем, что длинна массива осталась прежней из-за работы 
оператора delete(), который после удаления элемента оставляет на его месте 'Empty'. Решил  заменой на оператор .splice() - arrJSON.splice(indexDel, 1,)

Comment: Это как вариант